# surface that is created by the intersection of paraboloid and plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis

Find the surface that is created by the intersection of the paraboloid $x^2+y^2-z=0$ and the plane $z=2$.
$$x^2+y^2-z=0 \Rightarrow x^2+y^2=z$$
$$z=2$$

**EDIT**: I had to find the area of the surface that is created.

Can I find it using a theorem? Which formula could I use?

Comment: You are right but replace "$\tt surface$" by "$\tt curve$".

Comment: But..I want to find the surface!!!How can I do this??

Comment: Ah... $\left\{\left(x,y\right)\ \ni\ x^{2} + y^{2} < 2\right\}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Why is it like that?? I haven't understood..

Comment: It's a curve a I know that. OP 'want' a surface. I 'guess' OP is talking about the surface enclosed by the curve. Any way, it's not clear...

Comment: @FelixMarin The exercise requires to calculate the area of the surface that is created...Can I find it using a theorem?

Comment: "The surface that is created" is ambiguous.  You started with two surfaces: a paraboloid and a plane. They are infinite, but each of them is cut in two pieces by the other. The paraboloid cuts a disk out of the plane, and the plane cuts a parabolic "cup" off the "end" of the paraboloid. The disk and the "cup" both have finite areas. Which one do you want? In either case, someone has given the answer already in considerable detail. The only detail that is missing is in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Almost right: it's in $3$-dimensional space, not $2$-dimensional.  So the center is $(0,0,2)$ and the circle is in the plane $z=2$.

Comment: So,is the asked surface a sphere or a circle???

Comment: It is a circle as Robert said in the plane $z=2$

Comment: ... and it is not a surface, it is a curve.

Comment: Do you maybe know can I can find the area of the surface that is created?

Comment: You don't know how to find the area of a circle?

Comment: Is the area of a circle with radius $r$: $$\pi r^2$$?

Comment: Why do you need to ask?

Comment: A circle does not change in the 3 dimension space its still a circle, if you are looking for a powerfull theorem : [Green's Theorem](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Green#Calculs_d.27aires) , the french wiki gives an exemple with an elliptic curve ..

Answer (score 2):

It seems that we have to calculate the area of  the paraboloid contained between the planes $z=0$ and $z=2$. The meridian curve of this surface $S$ is given by
$$z=f(r):=r^2\qquad(0\leq r\leq\sqrt{2})\ ,$$
which leads to the line element
$$ds=\sqrt{1+f'^2(r)}\ dr=\sqrt{1+4r^2}\ dr\ .$$
The surface $S$  can be visualized as a union of infinitesimal lampshades of radius $r$ $(0\leq r\leq\sqrt{2})$ and width $ds$. It follows that
$${\rm area}(S)=\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}2\pi r\ ds=\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}2\pi r\ \sqrt{1+4r^2}\ dr={\pi\over6}(1+4r^2)^{3/2}\biggr|_0^{\sqrt{2}}={13\pi\over3}\ .$$

Comment: But...with this formula:
$$\mathbf{r}(x,y) = x \hat \imath + y \hat \jmath + (x^2+y^2) \hat k$$
that I like Serena mentioned we get $\frac{26 \pi}{6}$ .
Why do we find different results?

Comment: @evinda $\frac{26\pi}{6} = \frac{13\pi}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the paraboloid $x^2 + y^2 - z = 0$ and the plane $z = 2$. Like you said yourself, the intersection is the *curve* given by $x^2 + y^2 = 2$, which happens to be a circunference. But this is in $\Bbb R^3$, not $\Bbb R^2$, so we can parametrize the curve by $\alpha:[0, 2 \pi[ \rightarrow \Bbb R^3$, given by $\alpha(t) = (\sqrt{2} \cos t, \sqrt{2} \sin t, 2)$, because the radius is $\sqrt{2}$, and the $2$ in the last component is because the circunference is contained in the plane $z=2$ (intersection, right?).

Although it's not necessary, we can go further and parametrize the *surface* which has the circunference above as boundary, and is contained in the plane $z=2$ by $X: [0, \sqrt{2}] \times [0, 2\pi[ \rightarrow \Bbb R^3$, given by $X(u,v) = (u \cos v, u \sin v, 2)$. Again, the $2$ in the last component is because the *disc* is contained in the plane $z=2$. The $v$ parameter will do the role of the angle, and $u$ will be the radius. Letting the radius vary from $0$ to $\sqrt{2}$, we get the points *inside* the disc.

In a general situation, you can do an surface integral to find the area, but in this case, since we ended up with a circunference, we can use the simple fact that the area of a disc with radius $r$ is given by $\pi r^2$. Hence, the area of the surface will be $2 \pi$. Try to draw everything I said here so you can understand this better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula:
$$A=\iint_T\left \| \frac{\partial{\mathbf{r}}}{\partial{x}} \times \frac{\partial{\mathbf{r}}}{\partial{y}}\right \| dxdy$$
with:
$$\mathbf{r}(x,y) = x \hat \imath + y \hat \jmath + (x^2+y^2) \hat k$$
See [Surface integrals of scalar fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_scalar_fields) on wiki.